# Django Error with custom login model

Tags: python, django

Hello I trying to make django custom user model but I am getting the following error. -

ERRORS:

> auth.User.groups: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'User.groups'
>   clashes with reverse accessor for 'Freelancer.groups'.
>           HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'User.groups' or 'Freelancer.groups'. auth.User.user_permissions:
>   (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'User.user_permissions' clashes
>   with reverse accessor for 'Freelancer.user_permissions'.
>           HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'User.user_permissions' or 'Freelancer.user_permissions'.
>   login.Freelancer.groups: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for
>   'Freelancer.groups' clashes with reverse accessor for 'User.groups'.
>           HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Freelancer.groups' or 'User.groups'. login.Freelancer.groups:
>   (fields.E331) Field specifies a many-to-many relation through model
>   'login.Freelancer_groups', which has not been installed.
>   login.Freelancer.user_permissions: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for
>   'Freelancer.user_permissions' clashes with reverse accessor for
>   'User.user_permissions'.
>           HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Freelancer.user_permissions' or 'User.user_permissions'.
>   login.Freelancer.user_permissions: (fields.E331) Field specifies a
>   many-to-many relation through model
>   'login.Freelancer_user_permissions', which has not been installed.
>
> System check identified 6 issues (0 silenced).

**models.py:**

```
from django.contrib.auth.tests.custom_user import CustomUserManager
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.utils.http import urlquote
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager, PermissionsMixin
from crm import settings


class FreelancerManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, name, skills, password=None):
        if not name:
            raise ValueError('Users must have a unique name ')

        user = self.model(
            name=self.name,
            skills=skills,
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, name, skills, password):
        """
        Creates and saves a superuser with the given email, date of
        birth and password.
        """
        user = self.create_user(
            name,
            password=password,
            skills=skills,
        )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class Freelancer(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    name = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                                related_name='Freelancer_profile',
                                verbose_name='name',
                                max_length=20,
                                unique=True, )

    field_of_interest = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    skills = models.TextField()
    experience = models.TextField()

    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = FreelancerManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'name'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['skills']

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'auth_user'
        verbose_name = _('user')
        verbose_name_plural = _('users')

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/users/%s/" % urlquote(self.name)

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.name

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.name

    def __str__(self):  # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.name

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        # "Does the user have a specific permission?"
        # # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, applabel):
        # "Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        # "Is the user a member of staff?"
        # "Simplest possible answer: All admins are staf"
        return self.is_admin

# class Clients(models.Model):
#     name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
#     firm_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
#     reference = models.CharField(max_length=200)
#     chu = models.CharField(max_length=200)
#
#     def __str__(self):
#         return self.name
```

**admin.py:**

```
# from django.contrib import admin
# from login.models import Freelancer
from django import forms
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.forms import ReadOnlyPasswordHashField
from .models import Freelancer


class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """A form for creating new users. Includes all the required
    fields, plus a repeated password."""
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Password confirmation', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = Freelancer
        fields = ('name', 'skills')

    def clean_password2(self):
        # Check that the two password entries match
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords don't match")
        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        # Save the provided password in hashed format
        user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user


class UserChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """A form for updating users. Includes all the fields on
    the user, but replaces the password field with admin's
    password hash display field.
    """
    password = ReadOnlyPasswordHashField()

    class Meta:
        model = Freelancer
        fields = ('name', 'password', 'skills','is_admin')

    def clean_password(self):
        # Regardless of what the user provides, return the initial value.
        # This is done here, rather than on the field, because the
        # field does not have access to the initial value
        return self.initial["password"]


class FreelancerAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    # The forms to add and change user instances
    form = UserChangeForm
    add_form = UserCreationForm

    # The fields to be used in displaying the User model.
    # These override the definitions on the base UserAdmin
    # that reference specific fields on auth.User.
    list_display = ('name', 'skills', 'is_admin')
    list_filter = ('is_admin',)
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('name', 'password')}),
        ('Personal info', {'fields': ('skills',)}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_admin',)}),
    )
    # add_fieldsets is not a standard ModelAdmin attribute. UserAdmin
    # overrides get_fieldsets to use this attribute when creating a user.
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('name', 'skills', 'password1', 'password2')}
         ),
    )
    search_fields = ('name',)
    ordering = ('name',)
    filter_horizontal = ()


# Now register the new UserAdmin...
admin.site.register(Freelancer, FreelancerAdmin)
# ... and, since we're not using Django's built-in permissions,
# unregister the Group model from admin.
admin.site.unregister(Group)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` setting to point to your Freelancer class, so Django knows not to load the default User model.

Also it makes no sense for Freelancer to have a OneToOne to User; it is a *replacement* for that model.

Comment: firstly thankyou sir it worked ...but now I'm getting these errors

login.Freelancer.groups: (fields.E331) Field specifies a many-to-many relation through model 'login.Freelancer_groups', which has not been installed.
login.Freelancer.user_permissions: (fields.E331) Field specifies a many-to-many relation through model 'login.Freelancer_user_permissions', which has not been installed.
message_board.Post.author: (fields.E301) Field defines a relation with the model 'auth.User', which has been swapped out.
        HINT: Update the relation to point at 'settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL'.